# Add my own table discover Tab Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, filebeat, heartbeat

anyone know, how i can seperate the date, so that it is not defined in @timestamp, that i can add my own table like @date? Anyone can explain it to me?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ktpdU.png)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read Kibana's [Index Pattern docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/index-patterns.html)

There are 3 options:

1. Hide the time column
   Go to `Stack Management` then `Advanced Settings` - search for the word `hide`.
2. Recreate the index pattern with a different time field.
3. Recreate the index pattern with no time field.

The Kibana docs will guide you through options 2 and 3.

Bonus option...

4. Use the `Saved Objects` API or UI to fetch the index pattern object, modify its JSON to reflect one of the changes from options 2 or 3, then upload it again. This will retain other index pattern settings (such as custom field presentations and scripted fields) in a way that would be lost with options 2 and 3.